# Rails 4 Button to Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a button which will send 100 points from the user to the owner of the article. For now, I wrote the following code, but Rails says:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Articles#show | No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"budgets", :id=>7}

What could be wrong?

Controller:

```ruby
 class BudgetsController < ApplicationController
    def upvote
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        if @article.budgets.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)
            @article.budgets.create
            @article.budgets.user_id = current_user.id
            @article.budgets.user_gill = 1000
        end

        @budget = @article.budgets.find(user_id: current_user.id)

    end
end
```

html:

```html
<div class = "row">
 <div class = "col-md-1">
  <%= button_to "＋", {:action => "upvote", :controller => "budgets",  :id => @article.id }%>
 </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```ruby
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    has_and_belongs_to_many :budgets
end


class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
    has_many :comments
    has_one :budget
end
```

Routes:

```
 resources :articles do
    resources :comments
    resources :budgets
  end
  resources :users do
    resources :budgets
  end
```

Comment: How do you have routes setup for `upvote`?

Comment: `button_to` method send a `POST` request by default.

Comment: I edited the routes. thank you @vee

Comment: I didn't create any routes for upvote, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :budgets do
  post :upvote, on: :member
end
```

[Rails Guide routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).